# Need help writing a RewriteRule to strip selectors in URL

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, aem

I need to write a simple rewriterule in apache for 2 conditions

1. Remove date selector from the js name
2. change the location /js/ into /jsmin/

Input URL: 
/etc/designs/myapp/clientlibs/basefooter/js/foresee/foresee-trigger.20160819.js

Output URL:
/etc/designs/myapp/clientlibs/basefooter/jsmin/foresee/foresee-trigger.js

I tried below Rule:

```
RewriteRule ^/etc/designs/myapp/clientlibs/basefooter/js/(.*).(0-9).js /etc/designs/myapp/clientlibs/basefooter/js/$1.js
RewriteRule ^/etc/designs/myapp/clientlibs/basefooter/js/(.*).js /etc/designs/myapp/clientlibs/basefooter/jsmin/$1.js
```

Note:

- All js are under /etc/designs/myapp/clientlibs/basefooter/js and get
  minified by maven during build into /jsmin
- There are more sub directories under js like /js/foresee/foresee.js

It works for the second rule, but first rule fails. Can you please help to write the rule?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regex needs to be modified

```
(.*)\.([0-9].+)\.js
```

Explanation

1. First group of brackets would match the folder and file name /etc/designs/myapp/clientlibs/basefooter/js/**foresee/foresee-trigger**.20160819.js
2. Second group of brackets would match the date /etc/designs/myapp/clientlibs/basefooter/js/foresee/foresee-trigger.**20160819**.js